# How to call Ajax query in java to check if email exist in database without refreshing the page in jsp and servlet

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I've a registration form in jsp and servlet code to register the user on database but I want to check if that email already exist in the database or not using Ajax call(because I don't want the page to be refreshed). But the problem is I am new to Ajax and don't know how to perform Ajax call.

Although, I've a written a simple logic to fetch the email if that exist in the database or not if exist, it prints the message as **[EMAIL] already registered** but it print the message in another page and I want this message to be printed below the submit button.

**Here is my JSP design code.**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Registration Page</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
if (document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value == "") {
/* document.getElementById('usernameErrorMsg').innerHTML='Username must be filled out'; */
alert("Username must be filled out")
document.forms["myForm"]["username"].focus();
return false;
} else {
document.getElementById('usernameErrorMsg').classList.add('d-none');
}

if (document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value.length <= 6) {
alert("Username minium of 6 character")
document.forms["myForm"]["username"].focus();
return false;
} else {
document.getElementById('usernameErrorMsg').classList.add('d-none');
}

if (document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value == "") {
alert("Name must be filled out")
document.forms["myForm"]["name"].focus();
return false;
} else {
document.getElementById('nameErrorMsg').classList.add('d-none');
}

if (document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value == "") {
alert("Email must be filled out")
document.forms["myForm"]["email"].focus();
return false;
} else {
document.getElementById('emailErrorMsg').classList.add('d-none');
 }

        if (document.forms["myForm"]["mobile"].value == "") {
          alert("Mobile must be filled out")
            document.forms["myForm"]["mobile"].focus();
                   return false;
           } else {
           document.getElementById('mobileErrorMsg').classList.add('d-none');
          }

          if (document.forms["myForm"]["mobile"].value.length <= 9) {
               alert("Mobile must be 10 digit")
               document.forms["myForm"]["mobile"].focus();
           return false;
                  } else {
                 document.getElementById('mobileErrorMsg').classList.add('d-none');
             }

    if (!(/^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im
            .test(+document.forms["myForm"]["mobile"].value))) {
        alert("Mobile number should be numeric only")
        document.forms["myForm"]["mobile"].focus();
        return false;
    }

             if (document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].value == "") {
           alert("Password must be filled out")
              document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].focus();
              return false;
          } else {
           document.getElementById('pwdErrorMsg').classList.add('d-none');
          }

           if (document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].value.length <= 4) {
               alert("Password should be minimum of 5 character")
                document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].focus();
            return false;
             } else {
            document.getElementById('mobileErrorMsg').classList.add('d-none');
             }
         if (document.forms["myForm"]["cpwd"].value == "") {
                 alert("Password must be filled out")
              document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].focus();
              return false;
          } else {
           document.getElementById('pwdErrorMsg').classList.add('d-none');
          }

           if (document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].value.length <= 4) {
               alert("Password should be minimum of 5 character")
                document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].focus();
            return false;
             } else {
            document.getElementById('mobileErrorMsg').classList.add('d-none');
             }
         if (document.forms["myForm"]["cpwd"].value == "") {
           alert("Confirm Password must be filled out")
              document.forms["myForm"]["cpwd"].focus();
             return false;
             } else {
            document.getElementById('cpwdErrorMsg').classList.add('d-none');
           }

         if (document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].value != document.forms["myForm"]["cpwd"].value) {
             alert("Password does not match")
         document.forms["myForm"]["cpwd"].focus();
           return false;
               } else {
          document.getElementById('cpwdErrorMsg').classList.add('d-none');
        }
       }
      </script>



           <body class="mt-10">
<%
    String login_msg1 = (String) request.getAttribute("ErrorForUserName");
    if (login_msg1 != null)
        out.println("<font color=green size=4px>" + login_msg1 + "</font>");
%>
<div class="m-auto text-center mt-5" style="margin: 10px 0 0 10px; width: 400px">
    <form action="Registration" id="signupform" name="myForm" method="post" class="mt-5 border px-4 py-5" onsubmit="return validateForm()" style="padding: 10px;">
        <h3>Member Signup</h3>
        <table class="w-100">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="create username"
                        name="username" class="form-control mt-2" /> <span
                        id="usernameErrorMsg" class="text-danger"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name"
                        class="form-control mt-2" /> <span id="nameErrorMsg"
                        class="text-danger"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email"
                        class="form-control mt-2" /> <span id="msg" class="text-danger"></span></td>
                    <!-- <span id="msg"></span> -->
                </tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="tel" placeholder="mobile number"
                        name="mobile" class="form-control mt-2" /> <span
                        id="mobileErrorMsg" class="text-danger"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="password" placeholder="password" name="pwd"
                        class="form-control mt-2" /> <span id="pwdErrorMsg"
                        class="text-danger"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="password" placeholder="confirm password"
                        name="cpwd" class="form-control mb-2" /> <span id="cpwdErrorMsg"
                        class="text-danger"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tr></tr>

        </table>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onsubmit="validate()">Register</button>
        <button type="reset" name="cancel" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
        <br /> Already Registered? <a href="Login.jsp" class="mb-2">Signin</a><br>
    </form>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function validate() {$("#email").live("blur",function(e) {
                                            $('#msg').hide();
                                            if ($('#email').val() == null || $('#email').val() == "") {
                                                $('#msg').show();
                                                $("#msg").html("Email is required field.").css("color", "red");
                                            } else {
                                                $.ajax({
                                                            type : "POST",
                                                            url : "http://localhost:8080/MyWebProject/src/com/myWebProject/UserDetails/Registration",
                                                            data : $('#signupform').serialize(),
                                                            dataType : "html",
                                                            cache : false,
                                                            success : function(msg) {
                                                                $('#msg').show();
                                                                $("#msg").html(msg);
                                                            },
                                                            error : function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
                                                                $('#msg').show();
                                                                $("#msg").html(textStatus+ " "+ errorThrown);
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                            }
                                        });
                    });
</script>
```

```
**Here is my Servlet Code**
 package com.myWebProject.UserDetails;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.PrintWriter;
  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.ResultSet;
  import java.sql.SQLException;
  import java.sql.Statement;
  import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession; 
  import com.myWebProject.db.DBConnection;

/**
  * Servlet implementation class Registration
 */
  @WebServlet(asyncSupported = true, urlPatterns = { "/RegisterUser" })
   public class Registration extends HttpServlet {
    boolean status;
    String emailValue;
    Statement pst;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    String userName = request.getParameter("username");
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String phone = request.getParameter("mobile");
    String password = request.getParameter("pwd");
    String confirmPassword = request.getParameter("cpwd");

    Connection con = DBConnection.connectDB();

    try {
        if (email != null && email.trim().length() > 0) {
            pst = con.createStatement();
            String fetchEmail = "Select email from UserDetails where Email=" + "'" + email + "'";
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(fetchEmail);
            if (!rs.next()) {
                String sql = "insert into UserDetails values('" + name + "','" + email + "','" + phone + "','"
                        + password + "' ,'" + userName + "')";
                status = pst.execute(sql);
                out.println("Registered Successfully");
                out.print("Click " + "<a href=\"Login.jsp\">Here</a>" + " to signin");
            } else {
                out.print("<span id=\"msg\" style=\"color:red;\">" + email + "</span>" + " is already registered. Click "
                        + " <a href=\"Login.jsp\">Here</a>" + " to signin");

            }
        } else {
            String sql = "insert into UserDetails values('" + name + "','" + email + "','" + phone + "','"
                    + password + "' ,'" + userName + "')";
            status = pst.execute(sql);
            out.println("Registered Successfully");
            out.print("Click " + "<a href=\"Login.jsp\">Here</a>" + " to signin");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    if (status) {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should create separate endpoint that verifies given email. When user types email in text-input, you make ajax call to that endpoint and send that email. You can get simple example of AJAX call here https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_first

Comment: Hi @NikolayShevchenko, can you explain in detailed way. As I am struggling with this problem from last 3 days and still no luck